# What has happened to my landcover data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, vector, land-cover

I have downloaded Great Britain vector landcover data from Digimap. I was expecting it to look like the image on the left, however, when I downloaded it to ArcGIS Desktop it only displayed 1 colour (right). I have also tried downloading 20m landcover data and the same thing happened.

What have I done wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is there any symbology file  (e.g. .lyr) that comes with the data download?

Comment: I have found the symbology file, however, I cannot add it to the ArcMap document. It does not appear when I try to 'match to symbols in a style'. The file says it is a .lyr file but when I put it onto the map it appears as a .tif.

Answer (score 5):

If the website doesn't provide a style file (.lyr) then you should manually assign a different color to each unique class. [The documentation in this zip file](https://data-package.ceh.ac.uk/sd/efb98222-5b9a-4d56-990d-5ab85eaf187e.zip) contains RGB colors in the image.

In ArcMap

- Open Layer Properties dialog box
- Navigate to `Symbology > Categories > Unique values`.
- In `Value Field` select the field referring the class name, the click `Add All Values`.
- Finally, assign the colors to each class by clicking the related color.

Here is the color codes:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have found the symbology file, however, I cannot add it to the ArcMap document. It does not appear when I try to 'match to symbols in a style'. The file says it is a .lyr file but when I put it onto the map it appears as a .tif. Do you know what I have done wrong?